# Image Slider Swiper function

Tags: javascript, image, slider, swiper.js

I am using swiper image slider and according to their API, i should be able to have a call back function but it is not working ..
what i am trying to do is that i have a container with text over my images with opacity: 0 and I have a css animation class that I want to be added to my container, so as soon as the page is loaded, I want  the animation to kick in on the first slide, next slide same rule , starts without the css class , add the css class to it

here is my javascript code

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        spaceBetween: 30,
        speed: 600,
        effect: 'fade',
        fade: {
             crossFade: true
        },
        onSlideChangeStart: function (Swiper){
            $('.slide-info').addClass('slider-text-animation ');
        },
        onSlideChangeEnd: function (Swiper){
            $('.slide-info').removeClass('slider-text-animation ');
        },
        loop: true,
        autoplay: 6500  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        mySwiper.on('slideChangeStart', function () {
            $('.slide-info').addClass('slider-text-animation ');
        });
        mySwiper.on('slideChangeEnd', function () {
            $('.slide-info').removeClass('slider-text-animation ');
        });
```

And also, take a look at their API.
http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/

Answer (score 0):

It's just simple with Swiper API, this would help you http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#parallax